# yocto recipe gives error -dev package contains non-symlink .so

Tags: yocto, packaging

I am trying to copy some of the precompiled libraries to my core-image-minimal using a recipe.
I am getting error below

```
-dev package contains non-symlink .so:scripts-dev path '/work/armv7ahf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/scripts/1.0-r0/packages-split/scripts-dev/usr/lib/libasm-0.148.so'
```

I am having some libraries like libasm-0.148.so, few .so which are not having any softlink to respective versioned libraries.

```
SOLIBS = ".so"
SOLIBS += ".so.*"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so"
```

I tried many changes in the recipe like below still getting same error or different error like added to package but not shipped. Above flags I tried in the recipe.

Comment: Could you check if FILES_${PN} and/or FILES_${PN}-dev aren't appended or set differently? Could you provide us the value of those variables so we can check?
You can check the actual values of those variables by doing `bitbake -e libasm | grep -e "^FILES_${PN}"`

Comment: FILES_${PN}     += "${base_libdir}/* ${sysconfdir}/* ${libdir}/*.so  {libdir}/.so.* /home/* ${libdir}/Qt-5.6.3/* \
/usr/lib/python2.7/* /usr/share/* /usr/local /usr/local/lib/* /usr/lib/ts/*".

Comment: i tried this command bitbake -e libdw | grep -e "^FILES_${PN}"
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libdw'. Close matches:
  libsdl
  libidn
  libdrm
  elfutils RPROVIDES libdw

Comment: when i enabled SOLIBS = ".so", I am seeing all versioned libraries in /usr/lib not getting packaged./usr/lib/libmenu.so.5.9                                                                                 
  /usr/lib/libtic.so.5.9
  /usr/lib/libffi.so.6.0.4
  /usr/lib/libspeexdsp.so.1
  /usr/lib/libtirpc.so.3.0.0
  /usr/lib/libperl.so.5
  /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.7.4
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
scripts: 199 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]

Comment: Sorry, misread. `bitbake -e scripts | grep -e "^FILES_${PN}"` because from the logs above, your recipe is named scripts.
`SOLIBS` can only be one string without spaces or weird characters. Because it is used directly in `FILES_${PN}` as a path without any logic behind (simple variable). If you want a mix of `.so` and `.so.*` libs, you would need to add `${libdir}/*.so.*` in `FILES_${PN}` and set `FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""`.
It seems your recipe creates a library which is wrongly formatted. IMHO, `libasm-0.148.so` most likely should be `libasm.so.0.148` and you should patch the Makefile.

Comment: Finally, I'm pretty sure you have an issue in your recipe because I don't think you should have libperl or libpcap packaged by your recipe. Same for `/usr/lib/qt-5.6.3` and `/usr/lib/python2.7` in `FILES_${PN}`, it smells fishy to me. What is your recipe supposed to give you as output of its build (using makefile, cmake, meson, autotools, whatever...)? There shouldn't be more than that in the `${D}` which is the install directory.

Comment: My recipe is not creating any library. My recipe copies already pre-compiled libraries & binaries from one rootfs image to yocto rootfs. I am getting errors while packaging the libraries.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add your recipe, what exactly you want to do (why do you want to take binaries from a rootfs image to put into the yocto rootfs), which binaries you want to install with this recipe? I'm confused at the moment and can't advise properly on what to test/check next.

Comment: I need to do a quick POC. I am migrating few of libraries like QT & custom applications build using QT outside of yocto. So i am copying binaries & QT libraries build on arago.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with pre-compiled packages take a look at:
https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/Packaging_Prebuilt_Libraries

Usually the following configs fix this type of issue:

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += " ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
```